# Multiple ways of performing an action with the page object pattern

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests

When implementing the page object pattern, the recommendation that I've seen is that actions should be high-level, instead of individual UI actions:

For example:

```
page.search(query)
```

Rather than:

```
page.enterSearchBarText(query)
page.clickSearchButton()
```

However, the search should also execute when the user hits Enter instead of clicking the search button.

So `search` could also be:

```
page.enterSearchBarText(query)
page.pressEnter()
```

If I want to cover both in my tests, what is a conventional way of implementing this? I thought perhaps

```
search(query, method)
```

where `method` could be one of `enum { SearchButton, Enter }`

Comment: I think the way you have suggested is the way I would do it. I try to favor enums over passing static strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 methods in that class

```
public void dataSearchBySearchButton(String query){

page.enterSearchBarText(query);
page.clickSearchButton();

}
```

And

```
public void dataSearchByEnterKey(String query){


page.enterSearchBarText(query);
page.pressEnter();

}
```

and you can call the relevant method which require in your test